# Store object in div and retrieve via Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, object

I need to store a Javascript object into a `div` (or in production: many divs). It really needs to go into the `data-object=""` attribute – i don't want to add it later via `$('div').data('object')`.

The below code only returns `"{"`... I feel like I have tried every combination of stringify and parse and whatnot.

Does anybody have a clue how to retrieve my object?

```js
var Module = {
  
  div: function() {
    
    var object = {
      name: 'one',
      type: 'two'
    };
    
    var html = '<div data-object="' + JSON.stringify(object) + '"></div>';
    
    var div = $(html).appendTo('body');
      
    // This just returns "{" instead of my object
    console.log(div.data('object'));
    
  }
  
}


$(document).click(function() {
  Module.div();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: have you inspected the element to see what it produces HTML wise?

Comment: I think you have to correct this line `var html = '<div data-object="' + JSON.stringify(object) + '"></div>';` to `var html = '<div data-object=' + JSON.stringify(object) + '>inspect here</div>';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `var html = '<div data-object="' + JSON.stringify(object) + '"></div>';`

With `var html = '<div data-object=' + JSON.stringify(object) + '></div>';`

No need to add the additional double quotes

```js
var Module = {
  
  div: function() {
    
    var object = {
      name: 'one',
      type: 'two'
    };
    
    var html = '<div data-object=' + JSON.stringify(object) + '></div>';
    
    var div = $(html).appendTo('body');
      
    // This just returns "{" instead of my object
    console.log(div.data('object'));
    
  }
  
}


$(document).click(function() {
  Module.div();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because JSON gets encoded using double quotes `"`, and you also encapsulate it between double quotes. The problem with this is that it produces :

```
<div data-object="{" name":"one","type":"two"}"></div>
```

so, when you read `data-object`, its value is effectively `"{"`.

Try encapsulating it into simple quotes :

```js
var Module = {
  
  div: function() {
    
    var object = {
      name: 'one',
      type: 'two'
    };
    
    var html = "<div data-object='" + JSON.stringify(object) + "'></div>";
    
    var div = $(html).appendTo('body');
      
    // This just returns "{" instead of my object
    console.log(div.data('object'));
    
  }
  
}


$(document).click(function() {
  Module.div();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now the output is valid :

```
<div data-object='{"name":"one","type":"two"}' ></div>
```

You can also set the attribute programmatically with jQuery :

```js
var Module = {
  div: function() {
    var object = {
      name: 'one',
      type: 'two'
    };
    
    var div = $("<div>")
               .attr("data-object", JSON.stringify(object))
               .appendTo('body');
      
    console.log(div.data('object'));
  }
}


$(document).click(function() {
  Module.div();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: your output : `data-object="{"name":"one","type":"two"}"`

Comment: But now the snippet works and the output is correct.

Comment: I agree, but if you inspect the element, the output is the one I wrote earlier

Comment: Yet it works. I have added an alternative solution to set the attribute programmatically instead of concatenating stings.